# Meteor WaitOn for Collection subscription seemingly not working on template hooks

Tags: meteor

I've got a collection called `Listings` with 3 objects. I'm using the em scaffolding tool.

router.js (inside the both folder > router folder ):

```
Router.map(function(){

  this.route('Index', {
    path: '/',
    waitOn: function(){
      return Meteor.subscribe('listings');
    }
  });  

});
```

listings.js (inside both > collections)

```
Listings = new Meteor.Collection('listings');
```

index.js (client > views > pages)

```
Template.Index.rendered = function () {

    listings = Listings.find().fetch();
    console.log(listings);

}
```

When the page first loads `listings` console logs as an empty array. I then manually run `Listings.find().fetch();` and I get the three items in the DB.

Uhhh... I'm not sure why this is happening. `waitOn` doesn't appear to be working, at least completely. It doesn't seem to wait for the client to get the *entire* dataset for Listings before going to the route and rendering the template.

I can fix this problem by putting the code in `Deps.autorun`, in which case the console log works.

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
  listings = Listings.find().fetch();
  console.log(listings);
});
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to not have to use Deps.autorun?

Comment: Are you activating the default `loading` hook ? If you don't explicitly activate it your `waitOn` is useless as `iron:router` will render your template even though the subscription is not ready yet. `Router.onBeforeAction("loading");`

Comment: GAHHHHH yeah, that's exactly it. *sigh* Why does this happen? Why does IR need the `Router.onBeforeAction("loading");` (even if a "loading" template doesn't even exist!) just to make `waitOn` work like you think it should?